# How to get real time votes from a page into Power BI dashboard?

Tags: excel, office365, powerbi

Scenario :

I am presented with a website

I go in to that website and vote if i like horror movies, yes or no

And then i can see the result in real time, what people vote, and see the different types of mobile phones that they vote from, or laptop, in Power BI dashboard.

Is there a solution for this , i have searched the web, and havent found anything.

Answer (score 0):

That's a very broad question.  There are many potential solutions. You might start with https://github.com/PowerBI/getting-started-web-app-asp.net and embellish to your needs.

Lukasz P.

Power BI Team, Microsoft

Get started using Power BI APIs on the Power BI Developer Center - http://dev.powerbi.com. Keep up to date with the Power BI Developer Blog - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powerbidev.